# Creating multiple schemas for a user - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

Can we create multiple schemas for a particular user? I am currently logged in as X/Y user and when I tried creating a schema using `create schema authorization sample_schema`, I got the error `the schema name is missing or is incorrect in an authorization clause of a create schema statement`. I do know that a default schema `X` would have been created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CREATE SCHEMA` in Oracle does - contrary to its name - not create a new schema.

It is merely a shorthand to create several tables in a single statement.

Quote from the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6014.htm#i2154127):

> Use the CREATE SCHEMA statement to create multiple tables and views and perform multiple grants in your own schema in a single transaction

and further down the explanation on what the "schema" name parameter is:

> The schema name must be the same as your Oracle Database username.

Comment: So, how do I create new schemas for a particular user?

Comment: @darkie15: you can't. Users and schemas are the same thing in Oracle (it's a 1:1 relation)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could create a user named sample_schema (From the above example) and give user X/Y permission to use sample_schema tablespace.